# How do you center the main menu in CSS?

Tags: menus, theme-options

Do any of you know of a way to center the main menu on my company's site? I have been trying all day and am frazzled! I've tried editing the stylesheet but nothing has fixed it. I've tried throwing `white-space: nowrap` around in the CSS but it had no effect regardless of where I put it. Ahh!

We're using the Meta-Morphosis theme if that is any help.

I tried creating a link but I can't use our IP address link with the link tool in the post.

```
http://74.220.219.109/~dentalsp/
```

Please help! I am so frustrated. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
#catnav, #catnav ul {
display: block;
font-size: 8px;
line-height: 1;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
width: 594px;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! :D

Answer (score 1):

In your css edit the appropriate sections to this:

```
/* Cat Nav */

#menu { 
    background:#fff no-repeat top left;
    width: 100%;
    height:38px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
}

#catnav, #catnav ul {
    padding: 10;
    margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    list-style: none; 
    line-height: 1;
    width:750px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 8px;
}
```